# How to recode existing text filter for regex search and replace?

Tags: regex, text, vbscript, replace

I was able to cobble the code below so that it performs multiple search and replace functions as a text filter. The code works in the EditPlus text editor program.

I would like to execute the same idea except with regex search and replace.

What is the correct way to code for multiple regex Search and Replaces in a text filter?

`enter code here`

```
Option Explicit

Dim oWS, oFS

Set oWS = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set oFS = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'----------
' Script Setup
'----------
Dim oInStream, oOutStream, sInFile, sOutFile, nTotalLines, sArg

'----------
' Process File(s)
'----------
If Wscript.Arguments.Count = 0 Then
If InStr(LCase(WScript.FullName), "cscript.exe") <> 0 Then
sInFile = "StdIn"
sOutFile = "StdOut"
Set oInStream = WScript.StdIn
Set oOutStream = WScript.StdOut
Call ProcessFile()
Else
Call HelpMsg()
End If
Else
For sArg = 0 To Wscript.Arguments.Count -1
sInFile = Wscript.Arguments(sArg)
If IsFile(sInFile) Then
sOutFile = Left(sInFile, InStrRev(sInFile, ".") - 1) & ".lst"
Set oOutStream = oFS.OpenTextFile(sOutFile, 2, True, 0)
Set oInStream = oFS.OpenTextFile(sInFile, 1)
Call ProcessFile()
oWS.Run "NotePad.exe " & sOutFile
Else
Wscript.Echo "File Not Found: " & sInFile, , "Error"
End If
Next
End If

Call CleanUp(0)

'---------------------
' Subroutines
' ********************

'---------------------
Sub CleanUp(exitCode)
Set oInStream = Nothing
Set oOutStream = Nothing
Set oWS = Nothing
Set oWS = Nothing
WScript.Quit(exitCode)
End Sub

'---------------------
Sub ProcessFile()
'oOutStream.WriteLine "<DIV class='mesa'>"
nTotalLines = SeaRep()
'oOutStream.WriteLine "</DIV>"
End Sub

'---------------------

'---------------------
' Functions
' ********************
'---------------------
Function SeaRep()
Dim nLine, sLine, nCount, outPut1, outPut2, outPut3
nCount = 0
Do Until oInStream.AtEndOfStream
nLine = oInStream.Line
sLine = oInStream.ReadLine

outPut1 = Replace(sLine,"1a","foo")
outPut2 = Replace(outPut1,"2b","foobar")
outPut3 = Replace(outPut2,"3c","foosod")
oOutStream.WriteLine (Replace(outPut3,"4d","fooyard"))

nCount = nCount + 1
Loop
AddLineNum = nCount
End Function


'---------------------
'---------------------
Function IsFile (fName)
If oFS.FileExists(fName) Then IsFile = True Else IsFile = False
End Function

' ********************

' End code
```

Comment: Do you want to do pre-defined replacements programmatically in your script, or do you need to be able to pass arbitrary replacement strings it?

Comment: I work on projects that require the same replacements over and over again to text (xml, html) files. What I want to accomplish is to be able to execute a number of replacements in an open text file at the click of a button in my IDE (EditPlus). In the working sample code, above, there are four non-regex replacements. To answer your question, yes I want to execute regex S&Rs programatically. 

------ For entire directories, the most useful tool I have found (for my purposes) in the windows environment is ReplaceText2.2 It has an intuitive interface and does a great job.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm even more confused now. Do you want to replace text in a file opened in your editor? Or do you want to recursively replace text in all text files in a directory tree? In any text, XML and HTML file, or just one category?

Comment: Imagine you have one file open on your text editor. You need to run search and replace 10 times. With the code above, you press a button, all the changes are made. Later on in the day, same scenario different file, same 10 changes; you press the same button. The next day, new file, one click, same S&R x 10! The code above provides for that as a filter in the EditPlus text editor. Now, it would be useful to me if I could the same thing for regex search and replaces. (Same handful of S&Rs, over and over)---All in one shot, with one click.

Answer (score 2):

Replacing with regular expressions isn't that different from "normal" replacing. You just have the additional step of preparing the regular expression(s):

```
Set re = New RegExp
re.Pattern    = "1a"
re.IgnoreCase = True
re.Global     = True
```

The actual replacement is done like this (no search text, because that information is contained in the regular expression):

```
outPut1 = re.Replace(sLine, "foo")
```

Since you may need several regular expressions it's probably best to encapsulate their creation in a function:

```
Function CreateRegExp(str)
  Set re = New RegExp
  re.Pattern    = str
  re.IgnoreCase = True
  re.Global     = True

  Set CreateRegExp = re
End Function
```

Then your code might look somewhat like this:

```
Set re1 = CreateRegExp("1a")
Set re2 = CreateRegExp("2b")
Set re3 = CreateRegExp("3c")
Set re4 = CreateRegExp("4d")

'...

Function SeaRep()
  Dim nLine, sLine, nCount, outPut1, outPut2, outPut3
  nCount = 0
  Do Until oInStream.AtEndOfStream
    nLine = oInStream.Line
    sLine = oInStream.ReadLine

    outPut1 = re1.Replace(sLine, "foo")
    outPut2 = re2.Replace(outPut1, "foobar")
    outPut3 = re3.Replace(outPut2, "foosod")
    oOutStream.WriteLine (re4.Replace(outPut3, "fooyard"))

    nCount = nCount + 1
  Loop
  AddLineNum = nCount
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks Ansgar. I tried to incorporate your suggestion but I couldn't pull if off. I will keep investigating.